# Can't find my EF code first db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I know that there are some similar topic, but still I haven't found soultion.

I have create a simple ASP.NET MVC app with EF code first. I set no connectionstring, and everything works fine. I can perform CRUD actions and records are updated. But I don't know where my database is.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to connect to server. In Server name field I have tried to put: localhost, ., .\SQLEXPRESS, my Desktop name. These are all answears which I have found searching solutions.
Then in all cases I expand Databases/System Databases and all other Databases, but I can't find mine.

I know, that I can create an empty Database in Management Studio and set connectionstring to this DB (and it works), but I must send app to my teacher, and you know, he want to only click run, without setting up anything.

Have you got any solution?

Comment: Can you use Sqlite? That requires no setup, the database is just a dll in your project and it is fully supported by EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked in yourproject/App_Data? Usually, the DB files are created there

Comment: Thank you very much. App_Data was empty, but when I clicked 'Show All Files' it appeared there. I'm not sure if DB should be hidden, but finally I found it! Thanks!